# How to get the category ID in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to get the value of the category and say that if I am in a specific category such a text will appear and if it is not then another text will appear

```
$categories = get_the_category();
$category_id = $categories[0]->cat_ID;
if($category_id == 83){
  echo '123';
}else{
echo '1234';
}
```

This is what I tried to do and it doesn't work for me. Is there a way to make it work well?

editing:
It is important for me to note that I want to display within the post the number of the category to which the post is associated.

Comment: Are you using `get_the_category()` outside [The Loop](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/)? If so then you need to pass it the post ID as a parameter (eg. `get_the_category( get_queried_object_id() )`).

Answer (score 0):

WordPress Get Category ID from Slug

Here we pass the `$slug` to WordPress’ [get_category_by_slug()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_category_by_slug/) function. That gives us an object of useful category data, including the ID, which we then call directly:

```php
$slug = 'sales'; // assume Sales is category name you can get cat id from slug name
$cat = get_category_by_slug($slug); 
$catID = $cat->term_id;
```

Comment: And can I put this function inside the PHP code I wrote? which is in a file named X and not a function.php?

Comment: yes you can put any this code in your page-template or page in  wordpress.